# How do you bookmark a thread on EE Answers? (watch or follow)

Tags: discussion

As per the title of this question. Simply saving an interesting thread for later - how does that work on this Q&A site?

Comment: Not about EE. (I can only select the meta site to say it belongs on another site in the network)

Comment: It might seem finickity but please only post questions that relate directly to ExpressionEngine. If you need to ask general questions about StackExchange then it's probably appropriate to post in http://stackexchange.com/

Comment: Disagree with the flagging of this question - let's not alienate visitors. They're EE users looking to use our little corner of the StackExchange Q&A multi-site. New users need to know how to use it - I had exactly the same problem when I first joined, albeit I googled it and found the answer elsewhere.

Comment: There's a very definite remit for each StackExchange site so whilst I agree we don't want to alientate visitors we are also required to stick to the site's remit - in this case questions about ExpressionEngine.  Incidentally there is a "Help" link top right which provides a tour of StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

To the left of your question are two arrows to vote up or down. Beneath that is a star - click on it to bookmark the question. You can view all your bookmarks through your account page.

Comment: Brilliant Pete, as always!!

Answer (score 0):

Technically this should be asked in the Meta site, where questions about StackExchange and the running of this site can be answered.

https://expressionengine.meta.stackexchange.com/

There is also a "Help" link top right which has links to useful resources, explanations of how SE works, as well as a tour of the site/system.